# Threading in java with BasicPlayer

Tags: java, multithreading

My current issue is that I need to be able to know the status of the basic player instance at all times. This would require a thread to get the status while the scanner waits for input from the user. The status would be used to automatically play the next audio file. Things I have done. First I made sure that this code that works inline. Next I tried to it in the thread, to no avail. I think it has to do with syncing the object between both threads

I tried making a synchronized getter of the basic player instance but it did not work

```
public class Player implements Runnable {
private String song;
private boolean comp = false;
private String path;
private final BasicPlayer player;
public Player () {
    player = new BasicPlayer();
    path = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/src/Music/";
}
public void setSongName (String songName) {
    song = songName;
}

public String getSongName() {
    return song;
}
public void play () {
    try {
        player.open(new URL("file:///" + path + song));
        player.play();
        new Thread(new Player()).start();
    } catch (BasicPlayerException | MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private synchronized boolean isComplete () {
    return getStatus() == 2;
}

public synchronized int getStatus(){
    synchronized (player) {
        return getPlayer().getStatus();
    }
}

public synchronized boolean getComplete() {
    return comp;
}

public synchronized void setComp(boolean comp) {
    this.comp = comp;
}

private synchronized BasicPlayer getPlayer() {
    synchronized (player) {
        return player;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!isComplete()) {
        BackendUtils.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(getStatus());
        setComp(false);
    }
    setComp(true);
}
```

}

In this piece of code I am attempting to update a synchronized boolean to know then the audio is finished labeled comp. I try by using a synchronized player instance. The following code demonstrates how I tested if the threading was work or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BackendTesting {
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Player player = new Player();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        String input = input("$ ");
        if (input.contains("ply play")) {
            player.setSongName(input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1) + ".mp3");
            player.play();
        }

    }
}
private static String input (String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    return scanner.nextLine();
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of sleep you should be using wait and notify. Block the lock and as soon as the play is complete release the lock and notify all so that the other thread can pick it and play the next audio.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I am very new to threading what is "wait and notify" Blocking a lock and releasing a lock. Sorry if my question sounds stupid

Comment: This is what i replaced my run method with, i got an IllegalMonitorStateException `public void run() {
        List <String> songs = getAllFiles();
        int index = songs.indexOf(song);
        while (!isComplete()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(getStatus());
            setComp(false);
        }
        setComp(true);
        notify();
        setSongName(songs.get(index + 1));
        play();
    }`

Comment: you should call wait and notify method on a lock. Read below link, it will give you better understanding.

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/07/how-to-use-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

In the thread class

```
public void run() {
    MainClass.getInstance().playNextSong();
}
```

In the main class

```
public void playNextSong(){
synchronized(lock)
{
while (!isComplete()) {
        lock.wait();
    }
    setComp(true);
    lock.notifyAll();
}
}
```

Definitely you have to update it according to your needs.

Hope that helps.